# Difference between the phrases "annoy someone" and "bum someone out"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

What is the difference between the phrases "annoy someone" and "bum someone out"?

I have searched the meaning of both the phrases but I am still a little confused.
I think "to annoy someone" means to irritate someone and "bum someone out" means to irritate someone, bore someone and a kind of ruin someone's fun (means rain on someones parade).

And I also feel that "bum someone out" is of higher degree and quite more effective or kind of more offensive.

Please let me know if my information is correct or not.

Comment: Since you researched the phrases to get the meanings you understand so far, you should add some example sentences that you found, rather than have us guess the context. If there are a number of possible contexts, this could get confusing.

Answer (score 3):

> Bum out

It means "to make someone ​feel ​sad or ​disappointed" or "to make people sad, shocked and upset".

[Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bum-sb-out?q=bum%20out)

> Annoy

It is "to make someone ​slightly ​angry or ​upset".

[Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/annoy)

I'd agree with the fact that "bum out" is a little more sensitive where the scope of their meaning overlaps but do remember that "bum out" has a wider scope of its meaning and not always is it necessary that you can replace "bum out" with "annoy". I hope it helps.

Comment: I think To some extent " bum someone out " means to make the person feel a little ( or very little ) guilty for something . as it means to make someone feel sad, disappointed. Am I correct?

Comment: @Raunit : To make someone feel guilty and to make someone feel sad are two different things. I wouldn't say "to bum" is "to make them feel guilty"

Comment: can you explain me where to use this phrase with the help of same example scenario